# Is there good inductor calculation software?

Tags: inductor, software

What's a good software package for calculating all-around parameters related to inductors?  Not necessarily simulating them, but just static analysis with common quantities of interest.  I've used ELSIE, a version of which came with the ARRL Handbook at one time, but I'm just wondering what else is out there.  Preferably something that takes into account all relevant parameters for someone trying to build them by hand - turns ratio to voltage/current, wire gauge, core material, inductance, maybe B-H curve, and handles different types (regular air wound coils, toroid, maybe IF cans).

Comment: i think this counts as a shopping question

Comment: @DKNguyen Is this a bad thing?  I'm looking for a tool to assist me in engineering.

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: ask at https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @jsotola - Thanks for the tip.  I wasn't aware this was off topic here.

Comment: I wouldn't call this a shopping question @DKNguyen. The software OP is looking for is part of the design/thinking process, not software like a programming utility. Good design advice from experienced users here would be valuable. Unfortunately...any answer can only be an opinion and that is very off-topic as this is a Q&A site, not a discussion forum. Sorry, OP, and a very warm welcome to the site to you anyway, hopefully see you back with design questions or answers :-) In the meantime, there are other electronics discussion sites that will get you a better answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best I've found is the Coil32 software, available for free here [Coil 32 Calculator](https://coil32.net/)
most calculators, including the ARRL book, use Wheeler's formula to approximate air core multi-layer inductors, this calculator uses more advanced Maxwell equation algorithms, you can calculate both single layer and multiple layer air core inductors, aswell as ferrite core inductors.

Also useful for cored inductors is the free [Mini Ring Core Calculator](https://mini-ring-core-calculator.software.informer.com/download/). If you want something more advanced you'll have to look at EM simulation software such as CST.

Comment: Thank you for the recommendations!